# Can I create chef server from workstation?

Tags: chef-infra, server

It is obviously that chef server can do everything with nodes. So I can only "tell" chef server to connect to nodes and perform action. Can I do the same with sever inintialization from workstation? I mean there is setuped workstation and just installed machine for server. So I want connect to workstation and execute a cookbook (or may be a script) that connects to server machine and configure a chef server. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you read the model backway. Chef is a pull model and not a push model.

chef-client has to be installed and when it runs it connects to the server to retrieve what it has to do for the machine it runs on.

To install a chef-server, you'll have to install the package on the target node.
Configuring the chef-server is done with `chef-server-clt reconfigure` wich use chef-solo (a standalone mode of chef) to set up and configure all the services needed.

[More information here](https://docs.getchef.com/) and [here for the server part specifically](https://docs.getchef.com/install_server.html)